# How to add static properties in a generic interface

Tags: typescript

```
interface ICustomResponse<T>  {
  success: boolean;
  message?: string;
  ...T?
};

export const register = async (body: Body) => {
  const { data } = await axios.post<
    ICustomResponse <{ hasNickname?: boolean; hasEmail?: boolean }>
  >('/user/register', body);
  return data;
};
```

I would like to receive and use the `ICustomResponse` generic like the code above.
Since `success`and `message` are included in almost all functions, I want to add values statically and receive additional properties as generics, what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect the generic type with your `ICustomResponse` by using a type declaration like this:

```
interface MyResponse {
    success: boolean;
    message?: string;
}

type CustomResponse<T> = MyResponse & T;

const mock: CustomResponse<{ value: number }> = {
    success: true,
    value: 10,
    message: "message"
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&module=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8BKEDOAHAexBxQG8BYAKGRuRwFcEkccAuZAIwIIBsI4QAbiq1kAW1w44AcwgB+djjBRQ04ZQC+VKmHR4UAYXpKCY7PiIkAPABUAfMgC8aLLkLEUAMmQ31VBJZg4gQIANbsRiZmbpYQVqTIAG5wPPQQ7CD0YhzQyBoOzhTUtAxMkuzKaQA0IrTJqenIAIwADDXFNBIsMo0ARF1Ssr1UGoJAA)

Comment: Thank you.
But I have a question.'
`arrayBuffer`,`blob`
These properties can also be inferred, but can't you remove these properties?

Comment: @pvp11 I'm not sure if I understand you there. Do you want to remove certain properties from the generic type?

Comment: Yes. These properties have been added since I followed your code. Is there a way to remove it?
(arrayBuffer,blob,body,bodyUsed,formData,json,text)

Comment: @pvp11 If you want to do that you can use the utility type `Exclude` like this: `type CustomResponse<T, TExclude> = MyResponse & Exclude<T, TExclude>;` The properties from the second type parameter will be excluded from `T`

Comment: thank you
By the way `MyResponse & T`
Can you tell me why this code adds another property?

Comment: @pvp11 `MyResponse & T` defines an intersection between `MyResponse` and `T`, meaning that the resulting type will have all properties from both types. You'd have to show me the code in order to verify but I'm guessing that either your `MyResponse` or your `T` defines those properties.